# How to add a new row in sql from datagrid and update sql row from same datagrid?

Tags: sql

How can you add a new row in sql from datagrid, using textboxes in the footer and update sql row from same datagrid, using the edit of that row?

Comment: asp.net or winforms?  c# or vb.net?  or some other technology?

Answer (score 0):

This article on codeproject does a nice (thorough) job of demonstrating what you are asking.  It also comes with some demo code.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37430/Datagrid-Editing-Updating-Cancel-Selecting-Rows